# How to make a select Query with And

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

I want to make a select query with an `and` condition.

```
dept, divi, comp as string

Deparment = dept
Division = divi
company = comp
```

Tried this query:

```
Select *
from table
where
  department = '" & dept & "'
  and division = '" & divi & "'
  and Company = '" & comp & "'
```

The above query is working if the `dept`, `divi`, `comp` values are available.

Conditions

> If user select department only, it should display all value for that selected department only
>   If user select department and company means, it should display selected company and selected department for that company
>   If user select department, division and company means, it should display selected company, selected division for that company, selected department for that division.

How to make this select query?

Comment: what do you mean by available ?

Comment: @Gopal from what I understand you can try using select Case when (dept is not null  and comp is null and comp is null) then dept-value when (divi is not null and dept is null and comp is null) then divi-value when .... other conditions.... END from table.

Comment: @Sadiur, I modify my question.

Comment: Is this homework?  Are you using a programming language on top of the database?

Comment: is this tsql or linq in visual basic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this may help you:

```
Select *
from table
where
    (@dept = NULL OR department = @dept)
    and (@div = NULL OR division  = @div)
    and (@comp = NULL OR Company = @comp)
```

Comment: I like to write this where department = IsNull(@dept,department), you may run into some indexing issues later on though